# Writing code for database

Tags: sql-server, excel, database, vba

I am not an experienced coder so please bear with me and I hope this is explained adequately.

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database connected to a macro enables (obviously) excel spreadsheet which handles raw data and generates data series based of this. I use VBA.

For the purposes of this, I have x (time) and a variable y. 
x increases constantly at intervals ranging from 10 seconds to 15 minutes, whilst y may either vary considerably or not change much from each time step.
The database file is approaching 2GB which makes it unworkable, and I need to compress it or remove unnecessary data. I will consider horizontal partitioning if this fails..
The purposes of the data is to purely spot trends, so the necessary data that needs to remain will be that which enables the trend to still be noticeable. Any spikes or rapid changes to y over time will need to be kept in the database.
What I am hoping to do is to write some code which compares the rate of change and discard accordingly. 
I had the following in mind:

Begin:

If, yn to yn+1 for xn to xn+1, has a derivative greater than and a certain value, then KEEP in database.
If, yn to yn+1 for xn to xn+1, has a derivative less than this certain value then DISCARD yn+1 and xn+1, and compare yn to yn+2 , yn+3 etc… for xn to xn+2, xn+3 etc. until compared values derivatives are greater than a certain value. Then, begin process again from last value.

Also, because of the way the data management system is set-up, it means that there may be gaps in data shown (light blue). So if this can be accounted for that would be perfect i.e. the above comparisons are only done if xn - xn+1 < 2 hours (or another specified value). 
As you can see y may change considerably for a short duration (bright yellow) or hardly at all over a long duration (light blue). 
5 of the 23 Point IDs are shown in the graph..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGkDX.png)

Sorry for the poorly written exam styled question, but any guidance would be appreciated. As long as the integrity of the data remains and the user interface is reasonable then that would be perfect.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. If you can provide a snippet of your data, your explanation will probably make more sense. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: You seem to refer to a visualization of some kind in your description. But there is no link or graphic in your question - did something get lost along the way?

Comment: Sorry! Please find attached the image for the example.